# How do I install OpenSSL for PHP 5.3.5 on Windows XP?

Tags: php, windows-xp, installation, gmail, openssl

I want to send emails with GMail in my project, so I should enable OpenSSL (when I checked in phpinfo, that was disabled).

```
----> OpenSSL support disabled (install ext/openssl) )...
```

I am using that latest version of WampServer:

[DOWNLOAD WampServer 2.1e (32 bits)](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php)

```
 Apache 2.2.17 Php 5.3.5 Mysql 5.5.8
 PhpMyadmin 3.2.0.1 SQLBuddy 1.3.2
 XDebug 2.1.0-5.3 webGrind 1.0 XDC 1.5
```

My OS is Windows XP.

To install OpenSSL extension I went to this site: http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php

But I could not install OpenSSL.  What exactly should I do to install that?

Can anyone lead me step by step how to install `ext/openssl`?

Comment: Please reformat you question, remove double newlines and put configuration into "code" block.

Comment: IS IT OK NOW ? WHAT WAS THAT PROBLEM? I AM NEW IN THIS AREA / PLZ HELP ME FOR ACTING IN THE RIGHT DIRECTION ... THNAKS

Comment: i check this thread every hour , without any answers / am i in the right place about that question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you link to says what to do. You already have the DLL because you're using a recent version of PHP. You just need to make sure your PHP directory is in the path, following these instructions:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath